# SQL Server 2008 - excluding rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query

> DECLARE @ProductIdsToExclude nvarchar(max)
>
> SET @ProductIdsToExclude = '49506541-4CE2-40AC-812A-7AB262E6F0B0,49506541-4ce2-40ac-812a-7ab262e6f0b0'

I'm then using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_UDF_to_Parse_a_String.aspx?msg=2439257) function to parse @ProductIdsToExclude to a temp table:

> CREATE TABLE
>
> #TempProductIdsToExclude (ProductId uniqueidentifier)
>
> INSERT
>
> #TempProductIdsToExclude (ProductId)
>
> SELECT
>
> t.txt_value
>
> FROM
>
> dbo.fn_ParseText2Table(@ProductIdsToExclude,',') as t

I'm then using this query to pull out all *Products*:

> SELECT * FROM Products

My question is - how can I get the query to **exclude** all results where the *ProductId* in the *Products* table is contained within *#TempProductIdsToExclude*

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where not exists`:

```
select *
  from Products prod with (nolock)
 where not exists (select 1
                     from #TempProductIdsToExclude temp
                    where temp.ProductId = prod.ProductId)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use "with (nolock)"?

Comment: By default the entire `Products` table will be locked while the `select` is running, i.e. no other queries can access it. `with (nolock)` disables this locking to allow concurrent access - the downside is that if the table data is changed while the `select` is running, the results may differ to what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
select * from products where productId not in (select productId from ) #TempProductIdsToExclude)
```